# Same-origin policy for files - problem with iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, security

I am currently struggeling with the Same-origin policy for files: A completely file-based project of mine had been working for years until the policy has changed. The project consists of the index.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <iframe id="frame1" src="frame1.html" width="220" height="450"></iframe> 
          </td>
          <td>
            <iframe id="frame2" src="frame2.html" width="850" height="450"></iframe>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and two more files included as iframes (frame1.html and frame2.html). Within frame1.html and frame2.html I perform the following javascript call:

```
parentWindow = window.parent;
var frames = parentWindow.frames;
```

in order to acces data of the other frame via

```
frames[x].
```

followed by the desired property.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs it should work because both frames have index.html as their ancestor but (e.g. in Firefox) I am getting this error:

SecurityError: Permission denied to access property on cross-origin object

Can anyone help ? Do I probably have to remove iframes ? Any hint appreciated !

Thanks a lot in advance,
best

Alex

Comment: Are `frame1.html` and `frame2.html` on the same domain as the parent window file?

Comment: They used to be in a ./subframes folder. Placing them all into the same main directory leads to the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Anything related to direkt iframe-access failed, however, I figured an alternative that works well for me: Instead of direct communication between the iframes I am using the parent as a relay. In that context I am sending messages via

```
window.top.postMessage(['destinationIframe','desiredFunction',data1,..,dataX],'*');
```

from the iframes zu the parent, which forwards them to the destination iframe. Message reception at the parent and the iframes is realized via a listener:

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
    if (e.data[1] == 'xyz') {
       // do something
    }
};
```